# How to do a search on Deezer using its Android SDK?

Tags: android, deezer

I'm trying to use Deezer's Android SDK to do searches. However, the search results are always empty. Here's how I'm doing:

```
private final static String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[]{};
private DeezerConnect deezerConnect = new DeezerConnectImpl(DEEZER_APP_ID);
RequestListener handler = new CustomDeezerRequestHandler();

// User login
deezerConnect.authorize(MainActivity.this, PERMISSIONS, new MyDialogHandler());

// When the login is completed:
// Search request
DeezerRequest request = new DeezerRequest("/search/artist?q=radiohead");
deezerConnect.requestAsync(request, handler);
```

API result:

```
{"data":[],"total":0}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DeezerRequest object performs severall operations on the API path it's given (in your case "/search/artist?q=radiohead"). Among those operations, query parameters are reset to be compliant with the Deezer JSON API.

TO add your own parameters in such a request, a mechanism is provided in different constructors of the DeezerRequest object. Quoting from the SDK documentation :

> public DeezerRequest(String deezerServicePath,Bundle params)
>
> DeezerRequest constructor using the GET Method.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - deezerServicePath - Path to service. Matches the url of
>     the request minus the protocol and server host name part.
> - params -
>     Parameters passed to the service request. Parameters will be added
>     automatically via get or post.

So in your case, you should use the following method to create your request  :

```
    // Search request
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("q", "radiohead");
    DeezerRequest request = new DeezerRequest("/search/artist", bundle);
    mDeezerConnect.requestAsync(request, this);
```